# 変数宣言 "var hoge = (Clazz)null;" と "Clazz hoge;" の違い

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

タイトルの通りです。

変数宣言時に `var` で統一するために敢えてキャストして `null` を代入する方法と、

きちんと型を指定した場合で処理速度等のパフォーマンスに差が出たりとか、違いがあったりするのでしょうが？

私の妄想ですが、これくらいの差異、コンパイラがうまく最適化している気もしますが...

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var hoge = (Clazz)null;

    Clazz fuga;
}

public class Clazz
{
    // 任意のユーザークラス
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C#言語ではコンパイラはほとんど最適化を行わず、愚直にコード生成します。`null`代入のコードが書かれれば、

```
ldnull
stloc.0
```

とそのままのコードになります。

その上でこの程度のコードにコストはほぼかからないでしょうし、JITによる最適化で、差異はほぼなくなると思います。

---

別の視点で、`null`代入すべきではありません。適切なスコープで変数を宣言・代入することで、変数の値が常に有効になるようにコードを記述し、`null`になるタイミングを極力減らすべきです。
C#言語では変数を宣言しても値を代入するまでは参照できません。代入前に参照するコードはコンパイラーがエラーとして検出します。`null`代入するコーディング規約を定めてしまうと、これが有効に機能せず、コードが安全でなくなります。
当たり前ですが、変数が常に`null`にならないのであれば、`null`テストが不要になりコードがより安全になります。

加えてC# 8.0で[null許容参照型](https://ufcpp.net/study/csharp/resource/nullablereferencetype/)が導入されました。変数や戻り値が`null`になり得るかをコードで表現できるようになり、またコンパイラーがチェックできるようになりました。

以上のことから、`var hoge = (Clazz)null;`という表現は避けるべきです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
確かに ```null``` を許さないという観点は抜けてました。
私自身、```null``` 安全に対するスキルが乏しかったため、まずは ```var hoge = (Clazz)null;``` みたいな書き方はやめ、もう少し ```null``` にならない工夫をしていきたいと考え直しました。
ご教授ありがとうございました。

Comment: @neko3cs 結局、質問については解決したのでしょうか？

Comment: 解決しました。
あなたのアクションによって、解決した場合は回答左の✔をするとよいということを知りました。ありがとうございます。